# Can you automatically add Haskell import statements when extracting from Coq?

Tags: haskell, coq, coq-extraction

I'm doing an extraction from Coq to Haskell that requires importing a couple of modules on the Haskell end.  Is there any Coq extraction feature that allows you to do this automatically?  I know I could just write a script to do this but I'd prefer to not reinvent the wheel if necessary.

Comment: I don't think there is. I looked for ages and couldn't find any and wrote a script for it myself. I really hope someone answers your question in the positive though.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't, and it's very sad.

We've solved this problem with a Python script that adds several imports ([fiximports.py](https://github.com/mit-pdos/fscq/blob/master/src/fiximports.py)), but this requires using the Haskell preprocessor (you use it by passing `-F -pgmF fiximports.py` to `ghc`) and results in unused imports warnings, and isn't terribly elegant.

I think the issue is that these imports are unnecessary for OCaml extraction, and the feature hasn't been designed and implemented for Haskell extraction.

Comment: Is there a relevant issue on Coq's bugtracker?

Comment: I don't see such an issue.  Feel free to open one, though!  Note also https://github.com/coq/coq/blob/master/plugins/extraction/ExtrHaskellString.v#L11: `At the moment, Coq's extraction has no way to add extra import statements to the extracted Haskell code.  You will have to manually add: [...]`